# Generating a java.netSocket through true address and port

Tags: java, sockets, netcat

I have a server side application that is going to serve an Android application.

The server side application code has a java.net.ServerSocket in it and when i run below line in command line i can receive reaction on debug mode in Eclipse.

i can find java.net.ServerSocket through true address and true port with line:

```
nc 0.0.0.0 8650
```

----**EDIT**-----

I change a line of code and then try below line

```
nc 127.0.0.1 8650
```

----**EDIT**------

nc still can achieve to have reaction from debug.

I think i can find the socket because i get reaction on Eclipse Debug(Do you think am i right too?).

But to avoid complication, i do not paste server side code here.

Also i have some client code that i try to connect server socket through some address and port:

```
public static int port = 8650;
        public static String httpProtocol = "http://";

        public static String performRequest(String str) throws IOException {

            InetAddress serverAdr = null;


            //EDITED CODE BEGIN

            serverAdr=Inet4Address.getLocalHost();

            //EDITED CODE END

            Socket socket = null;
            String response = null;
            try {

                socket = new Socket(serverAdr,port);
                //socket = new Socket(serverAdr,port);//tried both this and above line
                BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socket
                        .getInputStream()));
                BufferedWriter out = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(
                        socket.getOutputStream()));

                out.write(str + "\n");
                out.flush();

                response = in.readLine();

                if (response == null) {
                    throw new IOException("no response recieved");
                }
            }catch(Exception e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            } finally {
                if (socket != null) {
                    socket.close();
                }
            }

            return response;

        }
```

By running above code, a java.net.Socket can not be created,

and i get exception

```
java.net.ConnectException: failed to connect to localhost/127.0.0.1 (port 8650): connect failed: ECONNREFUSED (Connection refused)
```

Where might the mistake be?

I can only guess i provide the same address and the same port with nc arguments and hope the java.net.Socket to become generated.

**EDIT**

Android device is a physical device and connected to host machine with USB.
I am on Ubuntu and i think i do not have a firewall.

I controlled by GUFW and firewall status is off.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot connect to IP address 0.0.0.0 because it is not a valid address. From [IP 0.0.0.0 on wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/0.0.0.0) *In the Internet Protocol version 4 the address 0.0.0.0 is a non-routable meta-address used to designate an invalid, unknown or non applicable target*.

By convention, it can be used to say any interface on localhost.

Comment: But when i debug serverSocket generation code i see 0.0.0.0. There is a possibility as i remember sth wrong. Anyway

Comment: I searched and found out sth i think. Tomorrow i am going to try something and return a feedback. Thanks

Comment: I edited the code and question, now do you have an idea, what is the mistake, thanks

Comment: Address 127.x.y.z is mapped to local host. So nc can access localhost, but if you lauch client from the android device, you try to access the server ... on the android device. Use `ipconfig` on Windows, or `ifconfig -a` on Unix to identify the ip addresses of all network interfaces.